# mit-scheme REPL with command line history and tab completion

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, mit-scheme

I'm reading [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) and I'm using [`mit-scheme`](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) installed on my os x 10.8 laptop via [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mit-scheme.rb).

Everything works as advertised, however I'm spoiled by the ease with which I get tab completion and command line history in REPL's for runtimes like Python and Node.js.

I'm not looking for anything heavy duty, but these features are pretty easy to come by in modern REPL's (it's just [a simple startup file](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#example) in Python and can be implemented in [a few lines in Node.js](https://gist.github.com/3317494)).

Is there an easy way to get tab completion and command history in the mit-scheme REPL without a heavy-duty application or having to switch to emacs (i.e. in an xterm terminal)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Install the [readline wrapper](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/README.txt):

`brew install rlwrap`

Once installed, `rlwrap scheme` will give you persistent history, paren matching, and tab completion. I typically use rlwrap with the following arguments:

-r Put all words seen on in- and output on the completion list.

-c Complete filenames

-f Specify a list of words to use for tab completion. I'm using an abridged list of bindings from the [MIT Scheme Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Binding-Index.html#Binding-Index). 
Rather than republish the list here, you can find it in [this gist](http://gist.github.com/3325982).
I have this file stored in "$HOME"/scheme_completion.txt

`rlwrap -r -c -f "$HOME"/scheme_completion.txt scheme`

```
1 ]=> (flo:a <tab tab>
flo:abs    flo:acos   flo:asin   flo:atan   flo:atan2  
1 ]=> (flo:abs -42.0)

;Value: 42.
```

Comment: Love this.  This seems really useful for other programs too.

Comment: Does something similar exist for Ubuntu?

Comment: For Ubuntu just sudo apt-get install rlwrap instead of brew install rlwrap

Comment: In order to make `rlwrap` respect `mit-schemes` way of using  CTRL+C and CTRL+G  to interrupt calculations, use `rlwrap` with `--polling` and a few extra lines in `.inputrc`; cf. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061825/is-there-a-fast-way-to-exit-the-debugger-in-mit-schemes-repl/66194555#66194555)

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend that you use [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), and use [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) within that to access both the REPL and to help with scheme file editing. It also makes dealing with various Scheme REPLs such as [Chez Scheme](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), [MIT Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Chicken](http://call-cc.org/), [Gambit](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [Chibi Scheme](http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/) effortless. [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) remains very well tuned to use with Scheme and LISP. Highly recommended.