# Is there a fast way to exit the debugger in MIT Scheme's REPL?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, rlwrap

Suppose I try to use an undefined variable in MIT Scheme's REPL:

```
1 ]=> blablabla

;Unbound variable: blablabla
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of blablabla.
; (RESTART 2) => Define blablabla to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

2 error>
```

This automatically brings me into the debugger. To exit the debugger, I have to type `(restart 1)`. Is there an alternative way that does not involve typing 11 characters just to exit the debugger? It's a bit silly that all three options involve typing 11 characters.

Comment: Just type ctrl+c ctrl+c

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thank you for the information. I was running MIT Scheme using rlwrap (`rlwrap mit-scheme`). rlwrap somehow causes the second ctrl-c to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Flux's answer, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>  twice will work with `mit-scheme`, but **not** when it runs within `rlwrap`

In order to make `rlwrap` more "transparent" with regard to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

- Use the `-W` (`--polling`) option: `rlwrap -W` will make `rlwrap` wake up every 40 msecs to check whether the client has changed its terminal settings (in your case, its [interrupt character](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Characters.html))
- Add a few lines to your `.inputrc`:

```
$if mit-scheme
  "\C-c" rlwrap-direct-keypress
  "\C-g" rlwrap-direct-keypress
$endif
```

Those lines will tell `rlwrap` (when wrapping `mit-scheme`) to pass on <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> even when in the middle of a line edit.

With those two tweaks, I can't tell the difference anymore in interrupt behaviour between rlwrapped and unwrapped `mit-scheme`

`-W` needs `rlwrap` >= 0.41, `rlwrap-direct-keypress` >= 0.43

For a more in-depth explanation *why* this works (and why the options and `.inputrc` entries are necessary) see [this rlwrap issue](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/111#issuecomment-779079014) on Github.

Comment: Should the `~/.inputrc` entries be enclosed in `$if mit-scheme ... $endif`?

Comment: Typos: `-w` should be `-W`, and `rlwrap -w` should be `rlwrap -W` instead.

Comment: (I corrected the typos, thanks!!). Yes, better enclose the lines in `$if..$endif` even though you will probably be allright when you don't (as the terminal will catch the CTRL+C before `rlwrap` can, and CTRL+G is seldom used.

Comment: I noticed that I don't even need to add those `rlwrap-direct-keypress` lines to `~/.inputrc`. `rlwrap -W mit-scheme` alone seems to solve the Ctrl-c Ctrl-c problem. Is this normal?

Comment: `-W` is the more important setting. Without the `rlwrap-direct-keypress`, for me sometimes the _first_ CTRL+C seemed to misfire. Apart from that, `-W` on its own will do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MIT Scheme user manual's section about [interrupting the REPL](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Interrupting.html):

> - C-c C-c
> - C-g
>
> Abort whatever Scheme evaluation is currently running and return to the top-level REPL. If no evaluation is running, this is equivalent to evaluating `(cmdl-interrupt/abort-top-level)`

So there are two ways to quickly exit the debugger:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> — Unfortunately, this method is unsuitable when using MIT Scheme with rlwrap (i.e. `rlwrap mit-scheme`). When in the debugger, `rlwrap` somehow causes the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to be ignored.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> — This works well with rlwrap, and requires less key presses than the above.